# Unable to delete an event from full calendar in the first attempt

Tags: jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have a Bootstrap modal plugin from which I am trying to delete an event created in FullCalendar. During my first attempt of deletion the event disappears from the calendar view but the mysql entry doesn't get deleted. The reason I noticed is `calEvent.id` is not getting a value during my inital attempt to delete but in the 2nd attempt `calEvent.id` has a value and I could delete the event successfully. I wonder why `calEvent.id` can't get the event id in the first attempt. Using the alert box I noticed at the first attempt I get a resut "undefined", I guess its because no value is coming `calEvent.id` .Please find my script below.

```
$('#event_delete').on('click', function () {                    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent.id);

    $.ajax({
           data: "&id=" + calEvent.id,
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://localhost/book/js/delete_events.php"                    
    });
    alert (calEvent.id);
    CloseModalBox();
});
```

--------------delete_events.php-----------

```
<?php
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', 'root', '');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "DELETE from evenement WHERE id=".$id;
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Show the PHP code in `delete_events.php` as well

Comment: I am sorry, I have added that now RiggsFolly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should be passed like this :-

```
$('#event_delete').on('click', function () {                    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent.id);

    $.ajax({
           data: {id: calEvent.id},
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://localhost/book/js/delete_events.php"                    
          });
          alert (calEvent.id);
          CloseModalBox();
});
```

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly for your quick reply. I noticed, `calEvent.id` is still not getting a value even after changing this. A workaround (not sure if its a recommended way) is to refresh the entire page and then I could get value to `calEvent.id`

Comment: Just noticed one more thing. this is only happening if I tend to delete an item just created. If the item was already created earlier (before previous page refresh), the `calEvent.id` has a value for that item.

Comment: I have no idea where you are getting calEvent.id from but it sound like something is wrong with the way that is being set when a new event is added to the calendar

Comment: Hey RiggsFolly, I guess I made a blunder in my code. I was trying to lookup calEvent.id which was only generated in mySQL. While creating an event, mySQL is creating an id and the full calendar receives the id every time the php page is refreshed ( I had an event to load data from mySQL during the load of the page.). To solve my current issue, I did a workaround by refreshing php page during a successful submission to mySQL DB which will force fetch data from the mySQL DB every time. You dropped the clue in your last statement which helped me figure out. Thanks mate ! +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the entire page you can call $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ). It will get all the events from your database and rerender them.